# How can you access the Control within a ControlTemplate in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, silverlight-3.0

I have the following code:

```
ControlTemplate ct = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(validXmlString);
```

Now I need to obtain the control that this template created, in my case, a Button. I have searched far and wide and can't find a simple explanation for how this is done.

Please note that for some unexplained reason, Microsoft provided a FindControl() method for ControlTemplate in WPF, but *not* in Silverlight. I've read that this can be done with the VisualTreeHelper, but I have yet to see an explanation for how.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing that...

Comment: Unhelpful response, Silverlight is massively flawed in its implementation of the DataGrid, and it's left me *no* choice but to do this. Do you have knowledge of how to do this? If so, please share it.

Comment: No choice? Maybe you are overlooking something, just what are you trying to achieve overall?

Answer (score 1):

Below you will find an example that loops through the Visual Tree recursively and finds all buttons adding them to a collection. You can check the name of the button etc.. and do what you need to do. I just used a collection as an example, as I found a quick sample on it.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<UIElement> buttons = new List<UIElement>();

        GetChildren(this, typeof(Button), ref buttons);
    }

    private void GetChildren(UIElement parent, Type targetType, ref List<UIElement> children)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                if (child.GetType() == targetType)
                {
                    //DO something with the button in the example added to a collection. You can also verify the name and perform the action you wish.
                    children.Add(child);
                }
                GetChildren(child, targetType, ref children);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps